# How to create this type of RDLC report?

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to achieve this type of Report in RDLC, in which 1 column remains fixed and it's relevant details are repeated in rows.

e.g.

```
 ApplicantName     UniqueNo          Type        Area     Covered     Amount 
   Mathew          87878f8d7         Commercial  21sqFt    20sqFT     20,000
                   829999999         Residential 88sqFT    70sqFT     90,000
                   865555555         Residential 90sqFT    89sqFt     80,000


   John            777777777         Residential 88sqFt    85sqFT     99,000
                   666666666         Commercial  77sqFT    75sqFT     97,000
```

so far I have done this:

[image]

Comment: That's what you *want*, but what do you *have*?

Comment: Looks like aggregation and cell merging

Comment: @DangerZone check my updated question now

Comment: @lad2025 I am unable to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to add grouping to you report. To achieve this:

- right click on detail row header
- select "add group" - "parent group" (under row group)
- select your "applicant name" field in "group by" dropdown

New column will be added to the left of your existing columns. Optionally you can select to add group header and/or footer. From your example, it looks like you should add footer to achieve blank line "break" between groups.